# A perfect factoring algorithm?

Tags: number-theory, reference-request, algorithms, factoring, computational-complexity

About factoring a composite integer $N$. As far as I know very little is known about how efficient an algorithm can be, but how about the opposite? What can be proved about how efficient it can't be?

Trial and error has a time complexity of $\sqrt N$ since it's enough to test for factors up to $\sqrt N$. Pollard Rho is supposed to have time complexity $\sqrt p \approx N^{1/4}$ where $p\leq \sqrt N$ is the largest prime factor of $N$.

Are there heuristic arguments showing that no general factoring algorithm can have time complexity $\log N$ or better?

Comment: Are you asking about algorithms for classical or quantum computers?

Comment: @Kyky - I know nothing about quantum algorithms, som for classical algorithms.

Comment: For quantum computers , the Shor algorithm is claimed to factor a number efficiently , but after taking a closer look at it (Wikipedia roughly describes it) , I am not convinced.

Comment: For classical computers , no efficient algorithm is known (RSA is based on the non-existence of such an algorithm), but I do not think that there are strong evidences that such an algorithm actually does not exist. By the way, RSA has not even be proved to be safe if the enemy is unable to factor the public number. Weirdly, it is nevertheless widely used.